# Apple TV Apps Question

Tags: apple-id, appletv

I shared an Apple Tv with my ex. We recently just broke up and she took the Apple Tv, even though it was linked to my personal Apple ID. I changed my password so my account can't be accessed anymore.

My question is, if I purchase and download apps through my iphone, such as a dating site like match.com, will those downloads be visible on the Apple Tv? Or since I changed my password, will none of my app information be obtainable? I want to confirm that they wont because I don't want to deal with the drama if so.

I appreciate the help and apologize in advance if this is a dumb question. I am not very technically saavy with electronics as it is very apparent.

Answer (score 4):

1. Head over to [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/)
2. Login with your user name and password
3. Head into settings.
4. Scroll down to my devices.
5. Click on the Apple TV you wish to remove.
6. That should open a dialog. There is a blue circle with an X in it. Click on it. That will disassociate your ID with the Apple TV.